# System of stochastic differential equations which yields a deterministic process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be given as solutions to the following system of stochastic differential equations

$$
dX = aXdt - YdW \ \ X_0 = x_0\\
dY = aYdt + XdW \ \ Y_0 = y_0
$$

Where the initial values are deterministic constants. Prove that the process defined by $R(t) = X_t^2 + Y_t^2$ is deterministic.

I tried calculating $Var[R]$ in hope that it would be equal to $0$ and thus $R$ will be deterministic. But I'm stuck at $Var[R] = E[X_t^4 + 2X_t^2Y_t^2 + Y_t^4] - E[X_t^2 + Y_t^2]= ?$

Comment: Is $W$ a Brownian motion here?

Comment: Yes. @nobody ....

Comment: Have you tried applying Ito's lemma to $X^2 + Y^2$?

Comment: Hmm no I did not. I could try, but I'm afraid I dont see why? @nobody

Comment: You should find that the terms in $dW_t$ cancel and since $[W]_t$ is deterministic you get a deterministic equation.

Comment: is this with respect to the same Brownian motion? Or two that are independent?

Comment: We don't know, i.e. it is not said in the exercise. @Nadiels

Comment: I found that $dR_t = (2aX_t^2 + 2aY_t^2 + Y_t^2 + X_t^2) dt$. @nobody

Comment: That's the same as $dR_t = (2a+1)R_t dt$ which is a deterministic DE.

Comment: Yeah, cool! Thanks. @nobody